# Different datatypes different execution plans bitmap scan vs index scan POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, query

I am currently working on a small presentation showing when postgresql will switch from index scan to bitmap scan to sequence scan.

First example (hint all index scan…):
Loosely based on a similar example of Schönig in Mastering Postgres by Packt.

```
create table t_test (id serial, name text);

-- add data
insert into t_test (name) select 'hans' from generate_series(1, 5000000);
insert into t_test (name) select 'paul' from generate_series(1, 5000000);

CREATE INDEX idx_x ON t_test(id);
analyze t_test;

--Index Scan using idx_x on t_test  (cost=0.43..1431.45 rows=42058 width=9) 
explain SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE id = 42353;

-- Index Scan using idx_x on t_test  (cost=0.43..1431.45 rows=42058 width=9)
explain SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE id < 42353;

-- Index Scan using idx_x on t_test  (cost=0.43..21.77 rows=419 width=9)
explain SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE id < 423;
```

So this example is not very good in showing when postgres will switch from index scan to bitmap scan.

`explain SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE id < 6002353;`
At around 6 mio retrieved lines pg will switch do seq scan.

Second example:

```
drop table if exists t_test;

create table t_test (id numeric, name text);

-- add data
insert into t_test (name, id) select 'hans', random() * 10000 from generate_series(1, 5000000);
insert into t_test (name, id) select 'paul', random() * 10000 from generate_series(1, 5000000);

CREATE INDEX idx_x ON t_test(id);
analyze t_test;

-- Index Scan using idx_x on t_test  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=16)
explain SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE id = 42353;

-- Seq Scan on t_test  (cost=0.00..179078.41 rows=9999873 width=16)
explain SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE id < 42353;

-- Bitmap Heap Scan on t_test  (cost=9955.65..69408.57 rows=429834 width=16)
explain SELECT * FROM t_test WHERE id < 423;
```

So this example is exactly what I wanted. But why the difference?
The example is almost identical. But I had to change the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re asking why the two queries with the WHERE id < 423 clause have different query plans correct?

Well the type of scan used is dependent on the actual characteristics of the table. Your first table uses a serial so it increments by 1 and there are only 423 rows to get so an index scan is most efficient. In your second example there you use a numeric and multiply that by a random so there are potentially quite a few rows in that filter and PG decides an index scan will not be most efficient.

TL;DR even though these queries and table properties look similar, your tables’ data is actually quite different.

Comment: You are right. I also completely overlooked the fact that I don't get the same results in the two examples. And I further guess that in example 1 pg never switches to bitmap scan because the data is in sequential order because of the serial type where as with random numbers pg has to assume random disk fetches. So there is just the choice between seq scan and index scan.